# Recommenderlab not giving topN list

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I created a dataset and tried applying `recommenderlab`, but am not getting a `TopN` list of recommendations. I got a list of `“i1”`, but expected three items.

I created a dataset with five items, five users, and ratings from 1:5 (plus `NA` values). UBCF is chosen with three items to recommend for the first user. `TopN` does not show after getting the different types of recommendations systems with `getModel()` function.

I am running recommender lab version 0.1-5 on RStudio version 0.98.953.

```
> #Get recommenderlab
> library("recommenderlab")
> #Create matrix
> Dt = matrix(c(NA,2,5,NA,3,
+               5,3,NA,2,1,
+               2,NA,4,1,1,
+               3,2,2,3,NA,
+               3,3,1,5,5), 
+             nrow = 5,
+             ncol = 5,
+             dimnames = list(user = paste("u", 1:5, sep = ''),
+                             item = paste("i", 1:5, sep = '')))
> #Identify matrix
> Dt

    item
user i1 i2 i3 i4 i5
  u1 NA  5  2  3  3
  u2  2  3 NA  2  3
  u3  5 NA  4  2  1
  u4 NA  2  1  3  5
  u5  3  1  1 NA  5

> #Convert matrix to RealRatingMatrix
> M <- as(Dt, "realRatingMatrix")
> #Identify dataset
> head(as(M, "data.frame"))

   user item rating
4    u1   i2      5
8    u1   i3      2
12   u1   i4      3
16   u1   i5      3
1    u2   i1      2
5    u2   i2      3

> # Create UBCF Recommender System 
> r <- Recommender(M, method = "UBCF")
> # Describe Recommender
> r
Recommender of type ‘UBCF’ for ‘realRatingMatrix’ 
learned using 5 users.
> # Get recommendation systems
> names(getModel(r))
[1] "description" "data"        "method"      "nn"          "sample"      "normalize"  
[7] "minRating"  
> # Get top-N model
> getModel(r)$topN
NULL
> # Create top-3 list from UBCF recommender system for users 1001
> recom <- predict(r, M[1,], n = 3)
> #Get recommendations
> as(recom, "list")
[[1]]
[1] "i1"
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

**Edit:**

I read on CRAN's recommenderlab documentation that the `predict()` function gives the predicted ratings or the topN list. For some reason, `predict()` is not giving either. Two `NA` values exist in the first row, but am only getting one item.

Answer (score 1):

The recommender won't recommend items that the first individual already rate.
If you include 3 NA's for the first user you will have a top 3 lists:

```
library("recommenderlab")
 #Create matrix
   Dt = matrix(c(NA,2,5,NA,3,
                                NA,3,NA,2,1,
                                NA,NA,4,1,1,
                                3,2,2,3,NA,
                               3,3,1,5,5), 
                               nrow = 5,
                             ncol = 5,
                             dimnames = list(user = paste("u", 1:5, sep = ''),
                                                                           item = paste("i", 1:5, sep = '')))

Dt
M <- as(Dt, "realRatingMatrix")
r <- Recommender(M, method = "UBCF")
recom <- predict(r, M[1,], n = 3,type=c("topNList"))
as(recom, "list")
```

Comment: Looking at the recommenderlab.pdf on CRAN, it states that predict can give the predicted values or all of them. Here's the text, "Predict can return either top-N lists (default setting) or predicted ratings. object is the recommender object, newdata is the data for the active users. For top-N lists n is the maximal number of recommended items in each list and predict() will return an objects of class topNList which contains one top-N list for each active user." I am looking for all the topN items, not just the recommended.

Comment: The topNList are based on the predicted values and predicted values are not generated for items already rated by the active users. The recommenderlab.pdf states p.22 "Predicted ratings are returned as an object of realRatingMatrix. The prediction contains NA
for the items rated by the active users. In the example we show the predicted ratings for the
first 10 items for the two active users." [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf).

Comment: Reading your edit: 
   recom <- predict(r, M[1,],type=c("ratings"))
   as(recom, "list")
with 3 NA's in the first row gives me 3 ratings. Check if you have modify the correct values in your matrix.